# function to change the extension to an image using matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make a function that read an image and change its extension, I want it recognize its original name and change just the extension so I get the name and later concatenate but i can't understand why is not working. I appreciate any help.

```
function salida = cambioFormatoImagen(x)
  y = imread(x);
  [pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts(x);
  nombre=name;
  concatena=strcat(nombre,'.jpg')
  imwrite(y,concatena);
  imshow(y);
end



>> cambioFormatoImagen
Error using cambioFormatoImagen (line 2)
Not enough input arguments.
```

Comment: You haven't given it an argument. Try `salida = cambioFormatoImagen('image.png')` or whatever image you want to read.

Comment: Do you want to change the file-type from e.g. `jpg` to `png` or just the extension, because you made a mistake in naming them? These are two different things...

Comment: I need to change .tiff to jpg on a file of images

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was to not use any input argument to the function.
I should have used something similar to:

```
salida = cambioFormatoImagen('image.png')
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer to your problem. To finally close it, you will need to accept the answer by clicking the grey check mark next to your answer to turn it green. (You can do this in a few days, as accepting your own answer is only allowed after 48 hours.) :-)