# Converting all images in a certain folder from .tiff to .jpg using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to convert all `.tiff`-files inside a certain folder to `.jpg`.
I have tried executing

```
ReadImgs('home/luisa/misc','*.tiff');
```

using the following function:

```
function X = ReadImgs(Folder,ImgType)
Imgs = dir([Folder '/' ImgType]);
NumImgs = size(Imgs,1);
image = double(imread([Folder '/' Imgs(1).name]));
for i=1:NumImgs,
    [pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts(Imgs(i).name);
    concatena=strcat(name,'.jpg');
    imwrite(y,concatena);
end
end
```

But I get this error:

```
>> codigoPruebas
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ReadImgs (line 4)
image = double(imread([Folder '/' Imgs(1).name]));

Error in codigoPruebas (line 7)
ReadImgs('home/luisa/misc','*.tiff');
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Instead of posting yet another question about this, you should better try to clarify your first one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653111/function-to-change-the-extension-to-an-image-using-matlab

Comment: I got to make work my previous question, what happened was that i didn't put input arguments a very silly mistake i am sorry but now i need to something more general but i just don't know what is happening

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of `dir`, it does return an empty struct. That's because you passed an invalid path. It's `/home/luisa/misc` not `home/luisa/misc`. Absolute path start with `/` relative path not.

Some additional advices in writing robust code:

- Instead of `[Folder '/' ImgType]` use `fullfile(Folder,ImgType)`. It's more robust (avoids duplicate file separators) and os independent.
- Use `im2double` instead of `double` to convert images. This automatically scales to 0...1

Comment: Also this code never reads the actual image, only the first. And `y` should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things wrong with your solution:

- The error you are getting is because you are trying to access `Imgs(1)`, even though it is empty. This is because you supplied a wrong file path: `home/luisa/misc` instead of `/home/luisa/misc`
- You only read the first image, as `image = double(imread([Folder '/' Imgs(1).name]));` is not inside the `for`-loop. (And only accesses `Imgs(1)` instead of `Imgs(i)`)
- `imwrite(y,concatena);` should use `image` instead of `y`, as `y` is never defined.

Implementing these changes will result in:

```
function convertAllToJpg(Folder,ImgType)
Imgs = dir(fullfile(Folder,ImgType));
for i=1:numel(Imgs)
    oldFilename = fullfile(Folder, Imgs(i).name);
    [~,name,~] = fileparts(Imgs(i).name);
    newFilename = fullfile(Folder, strcat(name, '.jpg'));
    imwrite(imread(oldFilename), newFilename);
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer， you can use it in your Matlab as a function
suppose oldFolder is store your origin image type
        newFolder is store your change image type
        ImgType is your origin image type
and you can change jpg whatever you want.

```
    function convertAllToJpg(oldFolder,newFolder,ImgType)
    Imgs = dir(fullfile(oldFolder,ImgType));
    for i=1:numel(Imgs)
      oldFilename = fullfile(oldFolder, Imgs(i).name);
      [~,name,~] = fileparts(Imgs(i).name);
      newFilename = fullfile(newFolder, strcat(name, '.jpg'));
      imwrite(imread(oldFilename), newFilename);
    end
    end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This doesn't answer the question, and also doesn't attribute the source of this code. You always need to attribute code taken from SO ([read the licensing terms](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) noted at the bottom of the page). You've taken knedlsepp's answer and added a `newFolder` parameter.